# Steps/declarations to make Unix shellscript to connect to DB2 Database

Tags: database, shell, unix

I want to write a Unix shell script which connects to a DB2 database and then does some insert,select queries.

Below message is displayed when trying to connect to DB through shell script.

> db2:not found
>
> db2:command not found

Question1: What are the declarations i need to make in shell script before writing the
command to connect to DB2.

Question2:how to find the db2path in unix

Question3:what is the reason am getting db2:command not found
How can i resolve this.

Note: Am working in an environment where am not suppose to make any configuration changes.Its similar to production.

Comment: how are you trying to connect to db ? you have to provide more info on what you have tried, its hard to suck out from the fingers and guess what you have tried ...

Comment: hi diemus,    db2 connect to dbname user uname using pword  added this line in the shell script . for dbname,uname and pword given the correct data.saved the script and executed.then i got the error message db2:command not found

Comment: are running it with superuser privileges ? again, please copy and paste the minimum working set of your script to your question text !

Comment: Not running with sudo access.     #!/bin/ksh
echo connect to DB
db2 "connect to DBXXXX user xxxx using xxxx"

Comment: is `db2` listed in `PATH` ? check with `whereis db2`

Comment: No its not listed.Am bit new to this.Could you tell me how to find the DB2PATH.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've managed to figure out from IBM documentations `DB2PATH` is not valid for *nix installations.

Just expand your the `PATH` to include the `db2` installation directory locally in your script and connect to you db.

To expand the path do smth like this in your script :

`PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2`

**NOTE :** `/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2` is just an example, you have to know figure out the correct `db2` executable location